# Is "welcome home" a complete sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

There are some sentences that do not require object pronouns:

```
Go.
```

Being one example, where the implied object pronoun (you) is omitted.

But can we have a complete sentence where both the subject and object are omitted, as in the case of

```
(I) welcome (you) home
```

Comment: I am not a linguist, but I believe this is what they call an [utterance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utterance) in distinction to a complete sentence.

Comment: @ThePhoton  The opposite utterance is even shorter and even less structured : _begone_.

Comment: @NigelJ, I understand an utterance can be shorter, even just "uh" or whatever. But does it have to be? I thought that a complete sentence is a kind of utterance but not vice versa.

Comment: @ThePhoton I would say that _begone_ and _welcome home_ are both utterances but are not sentences, but I await my betters to express their thoughts.

Comment: A sentence is an utterance that has a tensed verb and a subject in agreement with it. The subjects and verbs might not be there, like  _Get out of here_ and _Never been as far east as Maine._ But they'll be identifiable. If you want to say that _begone_ is an obligatorily imperative verb, like _beware_, and you want to say that imperatives are present tense (they're actually infinitive forms, but you can call them tensed if you want), then _Begone!_ is a sentence. _Welcome back_ and _Hello_ and _Thanks_ are politeness phrases, which may still have shreds of grammar, despite being frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Welcome home" is a complete sentence.  Welcome serves as an imperative in much the same way as "Stand up" is considered a complete sentence.  This is NOT an utterance or an exception to any rule

In the book, "[Commands: A Cross-linguistic Typology](https://books.google.com/books?id=8DooDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=%22welcome%20home%22%20as%20example%20of%20imperative&source=bl&ots=w7FDR71GNc&sig=ACfU3U1JrYNxn1q1Wv5WuOhUxwzBynT8eQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ19vi_IPnAhXaHM0KHeyiCWwQ6AEwBHoECGMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22welcome%20home%22%20as%20example%20of%20imperative&f=false)" found on Google books, page 179, the example of "Welcome home" is given as a non-command form of the Imperative.

[image: Commands: A Cross-linguistic Typology]